# iterating over loc on dataframes

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to extract data from a list of dataframes and extract row ranges. Each dataframe might not have the same data, therefore I have a list of possible index ranges that I would like loc to loop over, i.e. from the code sample below, I might want CIN to LAN, but on another dataframe, the CIN row doesn't exist, so I will want DET to LAN or HOU to LAN.

so I was thinking putting them in a list and iterating over the list, i.e.

`for df in dfs:
ranges=[[df.loc["CIN":"LAN"]], [df.loc["DET":"LAN"]]]
extracted ranges = (i for i in ranges)`

I'm not sure how you would iterate over a list and feed into loc, or perhaps .query().

```
  df1        stint    g    ab    r    h  X2b  X3b  hr    rbi    sb   cs   bb  \
year team                                                                    
2007 CIN       6  379   745  101  203   35    2  36  125.0  10.0  1.0  105   
     DET       5  301  1062  162  283   54    4  37  144.0  24.0  7.0   97   
     HOU       4  311   926  109  218   47    6  14   77.0  10.0  4.0   60   
     LAN      11  413  1021  153  293   61    3  36  154.0   7.0  5.0  114   
     NYN      13  622  1854  240  509  101    3  61  243.0  22.0  4.0  174   
     SFN       5  482  1305  198  337   67    6  40  171.0  26.0  7.0  235   
     TEX       2  198   729  115  200   40    4  28  115.0  21.0  4.0   73   
     TOR       4  459  1408  187  378   96    2  58  223.0   4.0  2.0  190   

  df2           so   ibb   hbp    sh    sf  gidp  
year team                                       
2008 DET   176.0   3.0  10.0   4.0   8.0  28.0  
     HOU   212.0   3.0   9.0  16.0   6.0  17.0  
     LAN   141.0   8.0   9.0   3.0   8.0  29.0  
     NYN   310.0  24.0  23.0  18.0  15.0  48.0  
     SFN   188.0  51.0   8.0  16.0   6.0  41.0  
     TEX   140.0   4.0   5.0   2.0   8.0  16.0  
     TOR   265.0  16.0  12.0   4.0  16.0  38.0
```

Comment: Do you want select from first value to `LAN`, like `df.loc[:"LAN"]]` ?

Comment: That might make things simpler but not always. It might not be there so I would extract to HOU. I will need to iterate over multiple data points to select the data I would need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution:

```
    import pandas as pd

    # Prepare a list of ranges
    ranges = [('CIN','LAN'), ('DET','LAN')]

    # Declare an empty list of data frames and a list with the existing data frames
    df_ranges = []
    df_list = [df1, df2]

    # Loop over multi-indices
    for i, idx_range in enumerate(ranges):
        df = df_list[i]
        row1, row2 = idx_range
        df_ranges.append(df.loc[(slice(None), slice(row1, row2)),:])

    # Print the extracted data
    print('Extracted data:\n')
    print(df_ranges)
```

Output:

```
    [           stint    g    ab    r    h  X2b  X3b  hr  rbi  sb  cs   bb
    year team                                                            
    2007 CIN       6  379   745  101  203   35    2  36  125  10   1  105
         DET       5  301  1062  162  283   54    4  37  144  24   7   97
         HOU       4  311   926  109  218   47    6  14   77  10   4   60
         LAN      11  413  1021  153  293   61    3  36  154   7   5  114 

                so  ibb  hbp  sh  sf  gidp
    year team                             
    2008 DET   176    3   10   4   8    28
         HOU   212    3    9  16   6    17
         LAN   141    8    9   3   8    29]
```